# CakePHP - Ajax form - submit on blur

Tags: ajax, forms, cakephp, submit

I am new to CakePHP and Ajax and I have some troubles using Ajax validations in a particular case.

As said in the title I submit the form on a jQuery blur() event. Each time an ajax request is done, on success we display a success.ctp that contains a little message.

Here my index.ctp

```
<h2>Edition - Id client : <?php echo h($id); ?></h2>
<hr>
<div id="success"></div>
<div>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Client', array(
        "id" => "ajax-form"
        ));
        ?>
    <fieldset>
        <?php
        //echo $this->Form->input('nom', array('onchange'=>"this.form.submit()"));
        echo $this->Form->input('nom', array(
            "id" =>  "nom",
            ));
        echo $this->Form->input('prenom', array(
            "id" =>  "prenom",
            ));
        echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
            "id" =>  "email",
            ));
        echo $this->Form->input('adresse', array(
            "id" =>  "adresse",
            ));
        echo $this->Form->input('ville', array(
            "id" =>  "ville",
            ));
        echo $this->Form->input('code_postal', array(
            "id" =>  "code_postal",
            ));
        echo $this->Form->input('pays', array(
            "id" =>  "pays",
            ));
        echo $this->Form->input('num_fixe', array(
            "id" =>  "num_fixe",
            ));
        echo $this->Form->input('num_portable', array(
            "id" =>  "num_portable",
            ));
        echo $this->Form->input('genre', array(
            "id" =>  "genre",
            "type" => "select",
            //"before" => '<p>Genre</p>',
            //"after" => '--après--',
            //"between" => '--entre---',
            "separator" => '<br>',
            "options" => array('' => '', 'Homme' => 'homme', 'Femme' => 'femme')
            ));
        echo $this->Form->input('date_naissance', array(
            "type" => "text",
            "id" =>  "date_naissance",
            "label" => "Date de naissance",
            "class"=>'datepicker',
            'empty' => true));
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker(
                    {
                        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                        language:'fr',
                        startView:'decade',
                        showToday: false,
                        startDate:'-80y',
                        endDate:'-18y'
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit(
         'Sauvegarder les modifications', 
        array(  'class'     => 'btn btn-primary',
                'title'     => 'Savegarder'
        )) ?>    


<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<hr>
<p>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link(
        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Retour',
        array('controller' => 'Clients', 'action' => 'index'),
        array('class' => 'btn btn-default', 'escape' => FALSE)
    ); ?>
</p>

<div style="display:none;" id="sending">Sending...</div>
<?php echo $errors; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#ajax-form input").blur(function () {


                $.ajax({beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    $("#sending").fadeIn();}, 
                    data:$("#ajax-form").closest("form").serialize(), 
                    dataType:"html", 
                    success:function (data, textStatus) {
                        $("#sending").fadeOut();
                        if(data.length < 50)
                            $("#success").html(data);
                    }, 
                    type:"post", 
                    url:"\/clients\/index\/<?php echo h($id); ?>"
                });
                return false;
            });


        });
</script>
```

My index function

```
public function index($id = null) {

        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }

        $user = $this->Client->findById($id);
        if (!$user) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }

        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            $this->Client->id = $id;
            $this->request->data['Client']['modified_at']   =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            if ($this->Client->save($this->request->data)) {
                if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){

                    $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                }
                else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('L\'utilisateur a été mis à jour.'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'recap', $id));
                }
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('Unable to update.')
                );
        }

        $user =  $this->Client->findById($id);
        $this->set('id',$id);
        $this->set('user',$user);
        if (!$this->request->data) {
            $this->request->data = $user;
        }

    }
```

And the model

```
public $validate = array(
        'nom' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Nom incorrect'
            )
        ),
        'prenom' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Prenom incorrect'
            )
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'message' => 'Email incorrect'
            )
        )
    );
```

The code works perfectly when data are valid. When they are not, i have to to use a fix to not show success.ctp:

```
$("#success").html(data);
```

That's what the 'if' do. Otherwise i got a duplication of index.ctp inside the success.ctp.

Is there an other way i could use Ajax validation on this blur() event, just like the submit button do.

Comment: Also, when there is an error in the form, other datas cannot be recorded in the database on blur

Answer (score 0):

You could could make and else if your form is unabled to be saved, put HTTP Header to 500 so ajax will trigger fail, and make a response with the validation errors. something like this:

```
        if ($this->Client->save($this->request->data)) {
            if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){

                $this->render('success', 'ajax');
            }
            else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('L\'utilisateur a été mis à jour.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'recap', $id));
            }
        } else if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
           $this->header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
           $this->set('data', implode(', ', $this->Client->validationErrors));
           //render a view that only echoes data var
           return $this->render('ajaxResponse');
        }
```

Then the ajax:

```
            $.ajax({beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                $("#sending").fadeIn();}, 
                data:$("#ajax-form").closest("form").serialize(), 
                dataType:"html", 
                type:"post", 
                url:"\/clients\/index\/<?php echo h($id); ?>"
            }).done(function(data){
                    $("#sending").fadeOut();
                    if(data.length < 50)
                        $("#success").html(response);
            }).fail(function(response){
            //alert with errors
                alert(response.responseText);
            });
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. But the success i use is a callback function, not the deprecated method. The done() method doesn't work. On the documentation of Ajax it is recommended to use the success/error/complete callbacks

Comment: I saw that they're not deprecated on callback... done works perfectly for me... is fail triggering on validation error?

Comment: I had issues on recording the textarea input with this method for some obscure reason, other inputs works well. With your method it was perfectly working with all field.

Answer (score 0):

Now, the error response is displaying when I fill a field with a bad value. I thought it could be better, instead of recording all the form, to just update the last field that was changed.

Should i use something like

```
$this->someModel->save( $data, false, array('someField') );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some improvements on way the form is working.
Before, having an error in form resulted in the failure of recording any other new valid data.

so I changed my script as

```
$.ajax({beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                        $("#sending").fadeIn();}, 
                        data:$("#ajax-form").closest("form").serialize(), 
                        dataType:"html", 

                        type:"post", 
                        url:"\/clients\/index\/<?php echo h($id); ?>?param="+key
                        //url:"\/clients\/ajax_form_field\/<?php echo h($id); ?>\/"+key
                    }).done(function(data){
                        $("#sending").fadeOut();
                        if(data.length>50){
                            $("#page").html(data);
                            if($("#nom-notEmpty").length == 0)
                                $('#ajax-form').before('<div id="nom-notEmpty" class="error-message">Merci de corriger les erreurs de saisie avant de valider le formulaire</div>');
                        }
                        if(data.length<50){
                            $("#success").html('message_sent');
                            $(".help-inline").remove();
                            if($(".help-inline").length == 0){
                                $("#nom-notEmpty").remove();
                            }
                        }

                    }).fail(function(data){
                    //alert with errors
                       alert(response.responseText);
                    });
                    return false;
```

Now i am adding a parameter in the Ajax request to get the name of field whom was changed.

Then I valid it in my controller with a switch

```
if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        $this->Client->id = $id;
        $this->request->data['Client']['modified_at']   =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');            

        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
            $data =$this->request->data['Client'];

            switch($this->request->query['param']){
                case "nom" :
                    if($this->Client->save( $data, true, array($this->request->query['param']) )){
                        $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                    }   
                break;
                case "prenom" :
                    if($this->Client->save( $data, true, array($this->request->query['param']) )){
                        $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                    }
                break;
                case "email" :
                    if($this->Client->save( $data, true, array($this->request->query['param']) )){
                        $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                    }
                break;
                case "adresse" :
                    if($this->Client->save( $data, true, array($this->request->query['param']) )){
                        $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                    }
                break;
                case "ville" :
                    if($this->Client->save( $data, true, array($this->request->query['param']) )){
                        $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                    }
                break;
                case "pays" :
                    if($this->Client->save( $data, true, array($this->request->query['param']) )){
                        $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                    }
                break;
                case "code_postal" :
                    if($this->Client->save( $data, true, array($this->request->query['param']) )){
                        $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                    }
                break;
                case "num_fixe" :
                    if($this->Client->save( $data, true, array($this->request->query['param']) )){
                        $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                    }
                break;
                case "num_portable" :
                    if($this->Client->save( $data, true, array($this->request->query['param']) )){
                        $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                    }
                break;
                case "genre" :
                    if($this->Client->save( $data, true, array($this->request->query['param']) )){
                        $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                    }
                break;
                case "date_naissance" :
                    if($this->Client->save( $data, true, array($this->request->query['param']) )){
                        $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                    }
                break;
            }
        }
        else{

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('L\'utilisateur a été mis à jour.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'recap', $id));
        }
```

It works. But I think there is a better way to do it with less code, in a more optimized way.

In addition of that, when the field have a wrong value, an error message is displayed under the field. But at each other validation, the message is cleaned by the ajax request. I am still working on that.